# Can't seem to have the variable from another table - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have these two classes but they cant seem to connect with each other. The error I get is :

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such column: user_points.user_id
```

Any ideas why this is?

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column('user_id',db.Integer , primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True , index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20))
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(20))
    surname = db.Column(db.String(20))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    dt_joined = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    points_rel = db.relationship('User_points',backref='pointers',lazy='dynamic')

 # User Points table
 class User_points(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user_points"
    id = db.Column('user_points_id',db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = db.Column('user_id',db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id'))
    fixture_id = db.Column('fixture_id',db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('fixture.fixture_id'))
    fixture_prediction_id = db.Column('fixture_prediction_id',db.Integer, \
                            db.ForeignKey('fixture_prediction.fixture_id'))    
    points = db.Column('points',db.Integer)
```

Any ideas anyone??? This is doing my head in :(

Comment: anyone have any ideas? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to drop the table and recreate it. It appears there was some issue with the metadata, the columns were there when I did .keys() although when I specifically named it in a select statement it couldnt find it. I cant explain why but dropping the table and recreating it worked.

Answer (score 0):

At `User` class try to define like

```
points_rel = db.relationship('user_points',backref='user',lazy='dynamic')
```

instead of using table name over class name. Hope that will fix your issue.

OR

Check Out This code

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True , index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20))
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(20))
    surname = db.Column(db.String(20))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    dt_joined = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    points_rel = db.relationship('User_points', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

# User Points table
class User_points(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user_points"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    fixture_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('fixture.fixture_id'))
    fixture_prediction_id = db.Column(db.Integer, \
                            db.ForeignKey('fixture_prediction.fixture_id'))    
    points = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Comment: I get this error when I use the table name: ArgumentError: Class object expected, got 'Table

Comment: No luck still this error: OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such column: user_points.user_id

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update at `User_points` class like `user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))`
Check it out.

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well but I get this: NoReferencedColumnError: Could not create ForeignKey 'user.id' on table 'user_points': table 'user' has no column named 'id'

Comment: it should be User.id rather than user.id. After that I get this error:InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.points_rel. Specify a 'primaryjoin' expression. If 'secondary' is present, 'secondaryjoin' is needed as well.